# NetBeans: execute all unit tests of all projects in 1 go

Tags: netbeans, junit

Unit testing some projects can take some time, and with multiple projects you have to start them one at-a-time sequentially. In NetBeans is it possible to run all unit tests for a single project in one go.

Is it also possible execute all unit tests for **all projects** in one go?

Answer (score 1):

> In NetBeans is it possible to run all unit tests for a single project in one go.

In NetBeans 7.1, yes, it is.  See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569008/how-to-run-all-junit-test-cases-from-netbeans/11522500#11522500) to this same question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it also possible execute all unit tests for all projects in one go?

I don't believe that this is possible.

> In NetBeans is it possible to run all unit tests for a single project in one go.

This is possible by right clicking the project node in the Projects explorer and choosing Test from the context menu. You can also use the key board shortcut Alt+F6 to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Netbeans also it is possible go to current project Properties by right clicking it, and go to Libraries, there u can add your other projects to run in a single go.